# How to add multiple additional files in .sumocfg (SUMO)?

Tags: xml, config, sumo, traffic-simulation

I have multiple Traffic Light Logics, each with specific signal plans.

I've defined each junction specific logic in a file:

```
J1.lgc.xml
```

When I try to add these files to configuration file (`J.sumocfg`)

```
<additional-files value="J1.add.xml"/>
<additional-files value="J2.add.xml"/>
...
```

I get this error:

> Error: Could not set option 'additional-files' (probably defined
>   twice).

is there any way to seperately load all these files instead of putting all in
one file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Multiple files can be added by comma-separation,

in the following example two files are added:

```
<additional-files value="J1.add.xml,J2.add.xml"/>
```